# Anaconda Navigator won't start : (Navigator Error) expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: anaconda, crash, anaconda3

I wanted to use Kite on Anaconda. Then I placed these YAML [codes from Kite website](https://help.kite.com/article/81-kite-and-anaconda) mistakenly into the `configure conda` and not into the `configure navigator` in the navigator preferences.

Then the navigator crashed and won't start.

I tried most available solutions on the net but none have worked. Then I uninstalled my Anaconda (which was the newest win-64 version) and installed `Ancaonda3-5.3.1` and nothing changes, but the Anaconda prompt works this time.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another `.condarc` file located at `C:\users\user\.condarc` file which was the reason for the crash. I opened the file and simply just wrote only the default values and it got fixed:

```
channels:
  - defaults
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `export CONDA_PREFIX=/Users/<YOUR_USER>/anaconda3` to your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc`) file.

If adding `CONDA_PREFIX` env var did not work, try removing `.condarc` file in `/Users/<YOUR_USER>` path completely. (worked on macOS)